# How to force a clustering algorithm to match expected results?

Tags: r, machine-learning, cluster-analysis

I have 2 dataset (data_A and data_B) with multiple variables. There are 2 possible output (pheno_1 and pheno_2). I know data_A has almost 100% pheno_1 and data_B has about 50% pheno_1. But the dataset are not labelled. I am looking for a clustering or classification algorithm that cluster my data in a way it match my expected results. Then I will use the clustering to predict the output of different datasets.

So far, I am using K-Means and try different set of variables and different normalization methods in order to get the final result I am looking for. I would like to find out a "automated" method that tries different combination until it finds what I am looking for.

no code to show for now.

Comment: Clustering algorithms are generally `unsupervised`. If you want to force a result to match your expectation you generally have to feed it some `supervised` information. Or you can try a `semi supervised` technique such as those found in the `RSSL` package.

Comment: What if this structure is not supported by the data? Or not by the variables of high variance? I think you ask for something impossible.

Answer (score 0):

In the R package **[ConsensusClusterPlus](https://bioconductor.org/packages/release/bioc/vignettes/ConsensusClusterPlus/inst/doc/ConsensusClusterPlus.pdf)** they have automated the process of finding clusters, such that the randomness of K-means is eliminated and such that several K-values are tested.

When it comes to your problem, then I would suggest:

1. Run consensus clustering on data_B
2. For each of the K clusters, calculate the "consensus" centroid
3. For each sample in data_A calculate the distance to the centroids from step 2, and assign each sample to the closest centroid.
4. Now you can assign all you data in both data_A and data_B a labels/clusters you can train a classifier using e.g. a random forest or XGboost.

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look into constrained K means. Here is an `R` [package](https://github.com/raagnew/Constrained-K-Means-Clustering-in-R) and a [paper](http://machinelearning102.pbworks.com/f/ConstrainedKMeanstr-2000-65.pdf) explaining the theory behind it. It should allow you to specify k constraints in which you can determine the limits of each cluster.